# I believe my question was closed unjustly

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

I asked a language design / theoretical [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/289462/banning-zero-argument-functions-what-problems-could-it-cause-in-a-hypothetica) and it was closed as "unclear what I'm asking".

The problem is not that it's unclear -- it's just a bit theoretical and language design-specific. There was a lively discussion going on, and the question certainly was concrete and direct:

> My question is whether such a design decision makes theoretical sense,
>   and whether it would have some **practical negative effects?**

I would also like to point out that only one of the people who closed the question seems to have **anything remotely close** in their history/badges to the topic of my question. I don't want to accuse them or anything, I'd just like the mods to consider the possibility that the closers might have not understood the question.

Could a mod reopen my question? I would like to answer it myself.

Comment: Thank you for the reopening, [here is my answer.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/289896/54627)